# override jquery validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to override the default message in jquery validation message I did as the documentation told but no use it is still show "This field is required." ?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Yrz7/

```
$(function () {    
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            email:"required",
            password:"required",
            messages: {
                email: "Please enter an email address.",
                password: "This field is required."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the documentation said to put the `messages` option _inside_ of the `rules` option.  Glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: "required",
        password: "required"
    }, // <-- here
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter an email address.",
        password: "This field is required."
   }
});
```

You need to close the `rules` before using `messages` here.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yrz7/4/)**

Comment: Minor quibble for clarification; it doesn't matter if the `rules` come "before" or after the `messages`.  The most important point is that `rules` and `messages` are _siblings_ and as such, you cannot put one inside of the other.  The exception is the `.rules('add')` method where the `messages` option goes inside.

Answer (score 0):

For using Validate plugin you have to add Rule first and then message.

The Scripts

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
            field1: {
                      required: true,
                      email: true
                    },
            field2: {
                      required: true,
                      minlength: 5
                    }
            }, // end of rules
   messages: {
                field1: "You cannot leave field1 blank",
                field2: "You cannot leave field1 blank"
              }// end of message


    });

});
```

The HTML

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="field1" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Options: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Methods: http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/

Standard Rules: http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/

Optional Rules available with the additional-methods.js file:

```
maxWords
minWords
rangeWords
letterswithbasicpunc
alphanumeric
lettersonly
nowhitespace
ziprange
zipcodeUS
integer
vinUS
dateITA
dateNL
time
time12h
phoneUS
phoneUK
mobileUK
phonesUK
postcodeUK
strippedminlength
email2 (optional TLD)
url2 (optional TLD)
creditcardtypes
ipv4
ipv6
pattern
require_from_group
skip_or_fill_minimum
accept
extension
```